# AirDrop on Unsupported Macs?

Tags: macos, macbook-pro, airdrop

One of the Lion features I would really like to use is AirDrop. It would make transferring files so much faster than using a flash drive. Unfortunately, my Mac is a 2007 Black MacBook, and AirDrop is not supported on this hardware.

Is there a way to enable AirDrop on my MacBook? Are there any hacks or Terminal tricks to do this?

Comment: Try dropbox, same features, easier to use, more versatile, plus online storage.

Comment: Dropbox is a very different set of features.  It may be a good alternative in some cases if you can't use Airdrop, but I would not want to transfer a large file between Macs by uploading it through my ISP and downloading it again.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

> Hackers have found that **Airdrop can be enabled on any Mac running OS X Lion**, and will work over ethernet as well. It can be enabled with a shell command.
> (source: [osxdaily](http://osxdaily.com/2011/09/16/enable-airdrop-ethernet-and-unsupported-macs/))

Copy and paste the command into the terminal of *all* macs that are supposed to communicate with other hacked macs.
This will enable AirDrop over both Wi-Fi and wired Ethernet connections:

```
defaults write com.apple.NetworkBrowser BrowseAllInterfaces 1; killall Finder;
```

To disable this feature use:

```
defaults write com.apple.NetworkBrowser BrowseAllInterfaces 0; killall Finder;
```

#### Note

This does not enable the feature on your Airport card. The AirDrop feature is originally not there because the Airport card does not support it (*simultaneous wifi and ad hoc networking*). This hack enables AirDrop to run over whatever other network connection you have. **Therefore, in order for two Macs to communciate this way both must apply the hack**.

Comment: Does this change remain constant through OS updates or will I have to reapply it each time the minor version changes?

Comment: @SynestheticSymphony I believe no, but I have not yet had to update my OS to a newer version (10.7.2) to confirm this. It would probably also depend on the type of update itself.

Comment: Is this really a hack? It's just a preference change. (It's still useful, just quibbling with terminology. (: )