# Can I use AirDrop if one or more of the participating computers is asleep/off?

Tags: airdrop

I'm currently AirDroppping 3 very large files and I need to know if the files will continue to transfer while I'm not using one of the computers.

Answer (score 2):

It should work as long as you have **Wake for network access** enabled in 
 **System Preferences → Energy Saver → Battery/Power Adapter**.

Depending on the capabilities of your Mac, the option's description may differ:

> - Wake for network access - Your Mac supports Wake on Demand over both Ethernet and AirPort
> - Wake for Ethernet network access - Your Mac supports Wake on Demand over Ethernet only
> - Wake for AirPort network access - Your Mac supports Wake on Demand over AirPort only
>
>   [[source](https://support.apple.com/kb/HT3774)]

The option "wake for Ethernet network access" is mentioned only to round up the answer. Wake on demand for ethernet will not help if your Macs communicate using Wi-Fi.

However, you can enable AirDrop to communicate using Ethernet as well as explained [here](https://apple.stackexchange.com/q/37825/13414). This will also enable AirDrop on so-called unsupported Macs.

Answer (score 0):

No, AirDrop requires a user to be logged in, which obviously means booted.

Comment: Okay...but what about asleep. The OP did mention asleep as well...